# Why control flow analysis applies to if else and not ternary operator?

Tags: typescript

When writing this code:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 'string';

let test;

if(true) {
  test = a
} else {
  test = b; // Unreachable code detected
}

test; // number
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjAbgFCkrARkmAcmgCcBLMAc0MwwBsBTWKB6WsgMwAooSBXBgEoYAbwwwYLaATgYAvjAZ0IDUeMmtYyXGhgB6PTACqYEgzjAAFnFyMYoACaqnLYCwfyMGKVF0GYYHwAtrgMJEA)

TypeScript correctly detects unreachable code and correctly infers `test` type to `number`.

However, this does not apply for the ternary operator:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 'string';

const test = true ? a : b; // 1 | "string"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAjAbgFCkrARkmAcmgCcBLMAc0My3GhigFMHkoSBXJmAfnhgBcMXGhgB6MahgAfGACJSFSnKA)

In this case TypeScript doesn't throw any error and doesn't detect that `test` can only be of type `1`. Why doesn't it?

Comment: I guess Typescript's unreachable code check is only done for statements, not expressions. That would be my guess, anyway. Or perhaps it has something to do with `if(DEBUG_MODE)` (with a constant) being used for control flow as a common pattern, but `DEBUG_MODE ? ... : ...` is not so common so not explicitly supported.